# Blind SQL injection - Get a time out and don't know why

Tags: sql-injection

During a CTF, I had the intuition that there was a blind SQL injection entry point in the URL. I tried to inject:

```
' UNION SLEEP(5);--
```

I was expecting to receive a response after 5s, but actually, I haven't received any. I got a timeout.

So there was definitely a blind injection at this point but why did I get a timeout when I did that? How could such injection prevent a response to be sent?

I don't think I can shut down the system with this kind of payload.

Comment: If the application is actually vulnerable to SQLi, one of the possible reasons could be that the injected payload is executed multiple times due to usage of the same value in multiple backend queries. You can reduce the time from 5 seconds to 1-2 seconds and try it again.

Comment: Interesting ! But I've also tried a SLEEP(1) and had the same issue

Comment: is there anything with a quote that returns?  Might be a side effect of an error.

Comment: Just that authentication has failed, a regular error message rendered by the UI.